# Performance difference when building a web form using controls vs placeholders

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a large list of forms that my company wants online and they require the forms be "locked" after the user fills them out and comes back to view their submission.  There are already a dozens of forms created using ASP.NET C# web forms, so I was told to pick up where the last developer left off.  They created a separate page for viewing, submitting and editing the forms, so if a change comes in, I need to make the same change in multiple locations.  I would like to create a user control for each form so I can use the same page in all three spots but I started to think about where I was moving the work to.

The first thing that came to mind was just doing an enable/disable on the fields and using CSS to style the displayed fields as text.  (And removing the button to save at the bottom when viewing)  This seems straightforward and I move the work for making a pretty form to the browser using JS and CSS.

Next, I looked at using a literal followed by the input field, switching the visibility to hide the input fields when a user is previewing a submission.  This doubled the number of controls on the page but I knew exactly which input went with which control.

My third thought was dynamically building the page by using placeholders and adjusting as needed.  This looked nice because I could store all fields and types in a database, allowing for quick ordering and changing the form without needing to touch the code.

My first idea seems to be the easiest but what is the difference in performance if .NET needs to build a form with 100+ controls versus dynamically building the form?  Is it better to build the entire page (or most of it) dynamically or have 100+ placeholders and build just the areas that need to be dynamic?  I don't want people to say "Sure, you made it easier to modify the form but it takes 20 seconds to load the page."

### ***Update 1:***

Taking [karl-anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1246391/karl-anderson)'s advice, I ran some tests.  I set up three pages that contained a table with the first cell being text ("Name:") and the second cell being the input (a textbox).  It was really straightforward but here are the rows:

**(1) Controls:**

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**(2) Multiple Placeholders:**

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Placeholder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**(3) Single Placeholder**: 
And for the last one, I had a single placeholder on the page and I built the table in the codebehind by using:

```
    Table tbl = new Table();
    for (int i = 0; i <= X; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell td = new TableCell();
        td.Text = "Name:";
        tr.Cells.Add(td);

        td = new TableCell();

        TextBox txtbx1 = new TextBox();
        td.Controls.Add(txtbx1);
        tr.Cells.Add(td);


        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    Placeholder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

Where X was the number or rows to add.

**Results:**

I loaded the page and then refreshed it 10 times, taking the average time it took for page load using .NET's trace:

(1) Controls:
Controls     Time (seconds)
 10               0.002089
 20               0.003204
 30               0.004530
 40               0.005943
 50               0.006821
100              0.013542
150              0.020033

(2) Multiple Placeholders:
Controls     Time (seconds)
 10               0.002604
 20               0.004419
 30               0.006507
 40               0.008509
 50               0.011194
100              0.024640
150              0.039748

(3) Single Placeholder:
Controls     Time (seconds)
 10               0.003501
 20               0.005794
 30               0.008264
 40               0.010616
 50               0.013048
100              0.024158
150              0.032826

The time it took to load when comparing a single control to a single placeholder went from almost ~24.6% long at 10 controls to ~98.4% longer at 150 controls.  Comparing the multiple controls to the single placeholder, it started off with a ~67.6% longer load time at 10 controls to ~63.8% longer at 150 controls.

I'm going to try working with the FormView (as suggested by [jadarnel27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861565/jadarnel27)) and I'll compare the results.

(I performed these tests on a Intel Xeon E5520 processor at 2.26GHz)

Comment: On an initial reading, it sounds like the [`FormView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227992(v=vs.100).aspx) control would actually work really well for your use-case. It provides "read-only", "update", and "insert" modes for a group of controls that you connect to a datasource. You could replace each of these three-page-sets with one page that contains a FormView.

Comment: Try making a prototype on a smaller scale than 100, say 10 controls and then bump it up to 20, etc.; you will be able to see if the performance degradation is acceptable or not.

Comment: So it sounds like having the single PlaceHolder definitely scales a lot better than multiple.  I'll be interested to hear what you find with your FormView tests.